# Using pointers in division of two arrays

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I need to store the results of two array's divisions in another array using pointers. But it displayed: arr3 = 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00

How should I use a pointer to calculating that division part?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
double arr1[10] = {10.0, 9.0, 8.0, 7.0, 6.0, 5.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0};  
double arr2[10] = {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,}; 
double arr3[10];
double *ptr=arr3;
int i=0;
    
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {   
        *ptr = arr1[i]/arr2[i];
        
        ptr++;
    }
    printf("arr3= ");
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        printf("%.2f ",*ptr);
        
        ptr++;
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to "reset" `ptr` after the first loop to point to the beginning of `arr3` again. Right now you are just going way past the end of that array (invoking *undefined behavior*)

Comment: You shouldn't use pointers here in the first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run at them as pointers as well. Also you needed to reset ptr to the head of the array after the first iteration.

```
double *ptr=arr3;
double *ptr1=arr1;
double *ptr2=arr2;

for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{   
    *ptr = (*ptr1)/(*ptr2);
    
     ptr++;ptr1++;ptr2++;
} 
ptr=arr3;
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    printf("%.2f ",*ptr);
    
    ptr++;
}
```

Comment: I think in the first for-loop you meant, *ptr = (*ptr1)/ (*ptr2)

Comment: Indeed I did. @SidharthRamesh

Comment: Thank you. I figured out the usage of it.

Answer (score 0):

you need to reset your `ptr` to `ptr=arr3;` before your second loop, since what you are doing now is filling values untill 9 and displaying from 10 to 19 (adresses relative to arr3)

Comment: Thank you for your help, I got the idea.